# Python ctypes create_string_buffer() Error 0xC0000005

Tags: python, ctypes, access-violation

I have a named pipe server with a main loop where I am reading data from a pipe:

```
while True:
        bytes_available = DWORD()
        ret_code = windll.kernel32.PeekNamedPipe(pipe, None, 0, None, byref(bytes_available))
        if ret_code == 0 and windll.kernel32.GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE:
            reconnect()
        buf = create_string_buffer(bytes_available.value)
        ret_code = windll.kernel32.ReadFile(pipe, byref(buf), bytes_available.value, None, overlapped_struct_ptr)
        if ret_code != 0 and bytes_available.value > 0:
            # process(buf.raw)
            pass
        elif ret_code == 0 and windll.kernel32.GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE:
            reconnect()
        windll.kernel32.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, byref(bytes_transferred), byref(completion_key),
                                                  byref(overlapped_struct_ptr), INFINITE)
```

Sometimes it crashes on the `create_string_buffer()` step with the following message:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

This seems strange to me, because if I replace `create_string_buffer(bytes_available.value)` with `(c_char*bytes_available.value)()` everything works fine. And if we look at the `create_string_buffer()` implementation, we will see, that it allocates the buffer the same way:

```
def create_string_buffer(init, size=None):
    """create_string_buffer(aString) -> character array
    create_string_buffer(anInteger) -> character array
    create_string_buffer(aString, anInteger) -> character array
    """
    if isinstance(init, (str, unicode)):
        if size is None:
            size = len(init)+1
        buftype = c_char * size
        buf = buftype()
        buf.value = init
        return buf
    elif isinstance(init, (int, long)):
        buftype = c_char * init
        buf = buftype()
        return buf
    raise TypeError(init)
```

So why does it fail?

Comment: `windll.kernel32.PeekNamedPipe()` call in your code seems to be missing an argument, there should be six, [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Bingo! I decided to omit the last argument because it was the last one and marked as optional. And I ignored the notice "This parameter can be NULL if no data is to be read." The funny thing is, it worked until I had lots of print statements in the code for debugging puproses. Python has started to crash after I removed print statements for the buffer. Could you add an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windll.kernel32.PeekNamedPipe() call in your code seems to be missing an argument, there should be six; see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779(v=vs.85).aspx)

Omitting an argument essentially caused undefined behaviour.